# TCPDF file_get_contents issue

Tags: php, timeout, file-get-contents, tcpdf

I am using Moodle 2.2 and using TCPDF to generate certificates for students. When user completes the course, Teacher should get the student's certificate as an email attachment.

For normal viewing of certificate I don't have any issue, but when comes to attachment I have to save it on server first. For that I have to invoke 'file_get_contents' method.

But I am getting error.

Code:

```
file_put_contents($CFG->dataroot.'/certificate/'.$USER->firstname.'_certificate.pdf', file_get_contents($certurl))
```

Error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://example.com/moodle/mod/certificate/view.php?id=84&action=get&uid=19):
>   failed to open stream: Connection timed out in
>   /usr/local/apache/htdocs/moodle/mod/quiz/view.php on line 290

It seems file_get_contents returns blank string. I tried cURL also. Both the options work fine to generate and view PDF online. But fails while saving it on server.

Note: I am facing this issue in my new server. It was working fine on my old server.

Comment: add this line at the beginning of your script `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I tried this but with no success. I am still getting the same issue. In fact the method **file_get_contents** is not able to hit the URL or convert the URL content into string. Hence I am getting zero kb PDF file and corrupted.

Comment: Justo another test, try disabling ipv6, restart apache and it should work now.

Comment: Tried to do that from php.ini but still it shows me turned on in phpinfo(). Any idea how to force it to disable ipv6?

Comment: Tell me your OS and version.

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

Comment: Follow these instructions http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-do-i-disable-ipv6-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html

Comment: Disabling ipv6 will help me solving this issue for sure? Can u pls brief me the reason once. I need to be very sure before doing this as I have to inform my PM and IT team as well regarding this change.

Comment: It[s a long answer, but you can read the details, here https://ctrl.blog/entry/php-file-contents-dual-stack

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I'll go through it and keep you posted.

Comment: No problem @Sudeep, glad to help :)